# why is my string not being recognised in my broadcast receiver - send SMS code

Tags: android, string, broadcastreceiver

I want `phoneNo`to be recognised in the scope of my `onReceive` method. What do I need to do ? I thought declaring it like this would do it, but no joy :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button sendBtn;
    EditText txtphoneNo;
    String phoneNo;

// register a broadcast receiver
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString(); etc etc....
```

At present my code looks like below. When the broadcast receiver detects a received SMS I want to print to logcat :

```
        System.out.println(origNumber);
        System.out.println(phoneNo);
```

But I can't make `phoneNo` recognised throughout the activity, only in the scope of sendSMSmessage.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button sendBtn;
    EditText txtphoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;

// register a broadcast receiver
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendSMSMessage();
            }
        });

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
//        the thing we're looking out for is received SMSs
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

            {
                //do something based on the intent's action

                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

                if (extras == null)
                    return;

                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
                String origNumber = msg.getOriginatingAddress();

                System.out.println(origNumber);
//                I want to print phoneNo here!!!!
//                System.out.println(phoneNo);

            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }



    protected void sendSMSMessage() {
        Log.i("Send SMS", "");
        String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (receiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            receiver = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're declaring `phoneNo` as a local variable of `sendSMSMessage()`, so it is not accessible outside of that method.

You should declare it as an instance variable instead.

Something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button sendBtn;
    EditText txtphoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;

    String phoneNo;

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendSMSMessage();
            }
        });

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
//        the thing we're looking out for is received SMSs
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

            {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

                if (extras == null)
                    return;

                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
                String origNumber = msg.getOriginatingAddress();

                System.out.println(origNumber);
                if(phoneNo != null) {
                    System.out.println(phoneNo);
                }

            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }



    protected void sendSMSMessage() {
        Log.i("Send SMS", "");
        phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (receiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            receiver = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha. I thought I'd tried this way. In any case, copy and pasted your code and now it seems to work fine.